# k8s pods ImagePullBackOff issue bitnami rabbitmq-exporter

Tags: debian, docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq, bitnami

In our scenario, We are facing an issue that fails to download the bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter from Dockrhub.

```
kubectl get statefulset rabbitmq -o yaml

 name: rabbitmq
        - name: RABBIT_URL
          value: http://localhost:15672
        - name: RABBIT_USER
          value: user
        - name: PUBLISH_PORT
          value: "9419"
        - name: RABBIT_CAPABILITIES
          value: bert,no_sort
        image: docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 6
          httpGet:
            path: /metrics
            port: metrics


 name: RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-erlang-cookie
              name: rabbitmq
        - name: RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-password
              name: rabbitmq
        image: docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.2-debian-9-r0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
```

but we have issue with the RabbitMQ matrics.

```
# kubectl get pods --selector app=rabbitmq

NAME         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-0   1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          5d15h
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
pod status 

rabbitmq-0                                             1/2     ImagePullBackOff             0                 5d15h
redis-master-0                                         2/2     Running                      0                 5d15h
It's not available in Docker Hub.

docker pull bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104
```

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

So, we are unable to download the bitnami/rabbitmq-exporter specific version as it is not available in the Docker Hub.

Would anyone be able to offer suggestions to address this issue? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

As rabbitmq-exporter:0.29.0-debian-9-r104 is not available, what is the alternative to be used for? compitable with bitnami/rabbitmq:3.8.2-debian-9-r0?

Comment: What CPU architecture are your K8s nodes? Bitnami only recently adding ARM64 support and not to all their charts.

Comment: @hardillb , node is based on the AMD64 (x86-64) architecture.
The label "beta.kubernetes.io/arch" and "kubernetes.io/arch" both indicate the CPU architecture of the node, which is "amd64".